# Which forum applications can integrate with Facebook?

Tags: facebook, forum, software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Forum Software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

What is the best/most compatible forum software which features almost complete integration with Facebook?

The main feature I ask is the Facebook Connect feature (user could use Facebook account to register). **But** it would be more perfect if other Facebook features could be integrated to.

Something like, subscribe thread which appears to Facebook notifications, easy sharing to Facebook, etc.

I have vBulletin, Invision Power Board, and SMF in my mind, but I'm open to more suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a forum using Drupal. I am almost sure there are many modules for Facebook integration. But it depends on your skills. Drupal might be a bit tricky for some people.

Comment: Drupal is more to CMS I think, their forum module is only an add-onn. I need a fully-functional forum software, since the CMS is already hanled with Wordpress.

Comment: Actually Drupal is more like Framework.

Comment: Oh you're right.. that's more like it. That's why I think Drupal is too big for this stuff, while I only need a forum software. :)